# How to store SQL column into an array(), PHP? (multidimensional)

Tags: php, sql, arrays, syntax

Perhaps this has been asked before, but I've been doing my research, and have yet to come up with an answer.

The column, `post_type` will categorize the "kinds" of post to be stored, ie) cars, news, animals etc.

DB scheme:

`id, title, type, content, date`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts";

$result = mysqli_query($link, query);

while ($row = fetch_mysqli_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
```

I would like to `$row` the `title` of all the **post_types** with `cars` only; therefore, should I make the post_type an array?

```
$category(
' ' => 'cars');
```

..if that's possible? Then I could $row the title of all posts pertaining to cars, only.

There may be an easier way via SQL syntax or something else that I'm overlooking, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you could already only query the posts containing 'cars': `SELECT * from posts WHERE type='cars'`

Comment: In an ideal world 'type' would reference to another table 'types' (with columns id, type), that contains the possible types. Then in the column 'type' you'd only store the id of the type.

Comment: Jeff's suggestion is good, if you are only concerned with a specific "type". Alternately, you can look at using array manipulation functions like `array_column` , `array_combine`, etc. You can easily convert the raw data output from mysql into your desired format.